shorter names for vue3 deep objects when accessing them in template and in code
How to get around long names of objects, for example, buttons.btnCancel.inactive? I've tried plain desctructuring using const {btnCancelInactive: inactive, btnCancelInactiveClass: inactiveClass, btnCancelActiveClass: activeClass} = buttons.btnCancel but I lose reactivity. I tried destructuring to toRefs but then even the value btnCancelInactive is empty.
Here is the complete code:
//vueAddItemPanel.js

const template = `
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <input 
       type="text"
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="Select a role to add..."
       ref="searchInputRef"
       v-model="searchText"
       >
      <button 
       class="btn disabled text-muted" 
       type="button">
       <i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
      <button 
       :class="[btnCancelInactive ? btnCancelInactiveClass : btnCancelActiveClass]"
       type="button"
       @click.stop="clearSearch">
       <i class="fas fa-x"></i></button>
    </div>
    sss {{btnCancelInactive}}
`

const {ref, reactive, watch, toRefs, } = Vue;

const vueAddItemPanel = {
    setup(props, ctx) {
        const searchText = ref('')
        const searchInputRef = ref(null)
        const buttons = reactive({
            btnCancel : {
                inactive : true,
                inactiveClass : "btn btn-outline-secondary disabled text-muted",
                activeClass : "btn btn-outline-secondary"
            }
        })

        const {btnCancelInactive, btnCancelInactiveClass, btnCancelActiveClass 
            } = toRefs( buttons.btnCancel )

        // note: debounce is from lodash
        const debouncedSearch = _.debounce(() => {
            ctx.emit('searchChanged', searchText.value)
        }, 500)
        
        watch( searchText, () => {
            buttons.btnCancel.inactive = searchText.value.trim() === ''
            debouncedSearch()        
        })

        const clearSearch = () => {
            searchText.value = ''
            searchInputRef.value.focus()
            buttons.btnCancel.inactive = true
        }

        return {
            searchText, clearSearch, debouncedSearch, searchInputRef,
            btnCancelInactive, btnCancelInactiveClass, btnCancelActiveClass,
        }
    },
    template: template,
}

export default vueAddItemPanel


To avoid losing reactivity and to make access easier in the template, use computed properties
    // Computed properties for easier access in templates
    const isBtnCancelInactive = computed(() => buttons.btnCancel.inactive);
    const inactiveClass = computed(() => buttons.btnCancel.inactiveClass);
    const activeClass = computed(() => buttons.btnCancel.activeClass);



I understand that this approach is only for the benefit of achieving shorter or more concise names in the template. I can take this as an answer.

It's done with computeds, as another answer suggests:
const btnCancelInactive = computed(() => buttons.btnCancel.inactive)

However, this can be done the opposite way, the values that are supposed to be used on their own can be fine-grained state:
const btnCancelInactive = ref(true);

They can be naturally aggregated into another state with Vue's ref unwrapping, but in this case this is not justified because there's no use for a single buttons state:
const buttons = reactive({
    btnCancel : {
        inactive: btnCancelInactive,
        ...
    }
})

Also, there's no problem with using long names in the template, as long as they are descriptive. But here this would result in long expression, while it's a good practice to move most of the logic to the script. If the intention is to have a clean expression for a class, a computed could be used like :class="btnCancelClass":
const btnCancelClass = computed(() => [buttons.btnCancel.inactive ? ...]);

